# My permessso will expire while I am in the UK. I am not an EU citizen but I have a green Turkish passport

Tags: italy, turkish-citizens

I am a student in Italy. I am planing to go to the UK for nye and Christmas and my permesso will expire while I am there. I have my permesso appointment receipt and I have my English visa too. I am not from the EU but I have a green Turkish passport, which allows me to enter all Schengen countries. Would I have any kind of problem while returning back to Italy?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91579/can-i-travel-to-from-italy-with-an-italian-residency-permit-application-receipt